# Netbeans cant call libraries in C++ since update to 12.04

Tags: c++, netbeans, libraries

I was hoping you can help me solve a problem I have. Since I updated to 12.04 version of Ubuntu I cant call libraries in C++ netbeans projects.

I get this message in netbeans when I include library in C++ program:

```
There are unresolved include inside <iostream>
```

I have tried to uninstall netbeans so I can reinstall it but when I run uninstall.sh I get critical error message:

Comment: It seems that the error message from uninstalling `netbeans` didn't make it into your question. You may want to edit your question to add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling the `g++` library or whatever c++ library you are using.

For g++,

remove it completely like

`sudo apt-get --purge remove g++`

Then do a `sudo apt-get update` to update all source

reinstall the library

`sudo apt-get install g++`

Clean Up user directory : ([Source](http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic19324.html))

Open netbeans, open netbeans `About` dialog. Have a look what is the path to your
userdir.

delete it (backup if you'd like) and start neat beans again.

Comment: it worked for me as well, thanks! I voted your answer, but the site doesn't accept my vote...

Answer (score 2):

This problem stems from changes they made starting with 12.04 where the path to the include folders is different.  Netbeans hasn't been updated to automatically find this new path system, so you're code assistance and project paths need to be changed.

To do this as late as 14.04, open Netbeans, go to the preferences dialog, and the C/C++ tab.  There you will find a code assistance tab with a list of absolute paths to certain folders.  Add /usr/include/c++/4.8 to the list, finalize that and close preferences.

Then, on the project you are working on, right click on the project icon in the side bar and go to the very bottom to find properties.  Click that, then on the C or C++ Compiler option, which ever one you're using, and there should be an Include Directories line.  Click the ellipsis on that line, and add the same path there.

Once you have that all closed up, your project should have proper code completion and compile correctly.  I hope this helps.

[Digital Fruit](http://www.digitalfruit.biz/techsupport)
[Our Blog](http://digitalfruitblog.blogspot.com)